# Hierarchical Extension of Chi-Square Test for Association

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, multilevel-analysis

I have data on a sample of people that are infected with a disease, and for each person I have which serovar (distinct variation of the bacteria) that they tested positive for. Each of these people belong to neighborhoods, each of which belongs to a city. Is there a way I can test whether there is a difference between the counts of each serovar between neighborhoods and between cities at the same time?

If I wanted to compare counts across cities, I could use a chi-square test for association, so my first thought was to use this test to see (a) are there difference between cities and (b) are there difference between neighborhoods within the same city. But is there a way to do that as one single, essentially hierarchical analysis?